# Binary tree in C#

Tags: c#, binary-tree

I'm trying to build a binary tree, but from some reason my code doesn't work.
Can somebody please help me?
I enter random numbers, and it...
I can't really explain it, it best to run it yourself and see the result in debug;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            leaf root = new leaf();
            while (true)
            {
                string read = Console.ReadLine();
                if (read == "print")
                {
                    root.print();
                }
                else
                {
                    root.grow(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class leaf
    {
        public void print()
        {

        }
        public void grow(int value)
        {
            if (isNull)
            {
                isNull = false;
                this.value = value;
                smaller = bigger = new leaf();
            }
            else
            {
                if (value > this.value)
                {
                    bigger.grow(value);
                }
                else
                {
                    smaller.grow(value);
                }
            }
        }
        public bool isNull = true;
        public int value;
        leaf smaller;
        leaf bigger;
    }
}
```

**The problem:**
For the input:
1
2
3
4
13
6
4
7
8

It generates the following tree(Skips numbers, and I don't know why):

```
   2
  / \
     4
    / \
       6
      / \
         7
        / \
```

Comment: You really should explain better what your problem is. Demanding that people spend time to figure out BOTH your problem and the solution...well, seems a bit lazy to me.

Comment: Have a go at explaining the problem -- you'll get a much better response :) And summarise it in the title too, although clearly "binary tree in c#" is interesting enough, it doesn't really help.

Comment: aside from explanation issues, kudos for being 14 and having the gumption to look at binary trees and get on stack overflow.

Comment: I tried to explain myself better for your understanding :). And thank you very much, that whats happens when a teenager has to much free time :)

Comment: With Jon Skeet's change, your code works fine on my PC, do you still have problems ? Otherwise you should set Jon's answer as `THE` answer...

Comment: It works partially. Look at the new explanation, from some reason the program skips every second number, and do not enter the number to either node of the tree.

Comment: @Gilad see my answer to why it "skips" I'm pretty sure the program expects a different input format than the one your using (Ie _two_ newlines pr. number not one)

Comment: Oh, I just tested the tree construction part, not the input from console eh eh :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that if you wrote precisely what you're doing the answer would be more clear.

You write that the input is: 1 2 3 4 13 6 4 7 8 but that would result in *nothing*
the line:

```
string read = Console.ReadLine();
```

would consume it and loop to the same line waiting for input. My guess is that your actual input is:

1

2

3

13

6

4

7

8

but swince every other of those would be consumed by the above line only 
2,4,6,7 would be consumed by the line:

```
root.grow(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
```

which corresponds to your result. changing that last line (after making the change Jon suggests) to:

```
root.grow(Convert.ToInt32(read));
```

will do the trick (if my assumptions on your actual input is correct)

Answer (score 7):

This is your problem, I suspect:

```
smaller = bigger = new leaf();
```

You've created *one* object, and assigned a reference to it for both `smaller` and `bigger`. Therefore calling `smaller.grow()` is equivalent to calling `bigger.grow()`.

Try this:

```
smaller = new leaf();
bigger = new leaf();
```

(As a side note, I'd *strongly* recommend that you start following the [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) to make your code easier to read for other developers, and more consistent with other code.)

Comment: Thanks. It's works better now. I edited the main with more info

Answer (score 1):

You should look this

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/BinarySearchTree.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/BinarySearchTree/Demo_and_Source_BinarySearchTree.zip